# Bootstrap 3: закрыть все модальные окна

Tags: bootstrap, javascript

Возможно ли закрыть все модальные окна без перебора?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все просто:

```
  $('.modal').modal('hide')
```

Объединяете их общим селектором и по нему делаете закрытие, он закроет все модалки.